# Heroku with junit 5

Tags: java, maven, heroku, junit

When I build my app in heroku with junit 5 don't working,
this happens on the push heroku

```
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  18.789 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-31T12:58:29Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project minhasfinancas: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_03ef1fbc/src/test/java/com/estudo/minhasfinancas/service/UsuarioServiceTest.java:[3,24] cannot find symbol
remote:        [ERROR]   symbol:   class Assert
remote:        [ERROR]   location: package org.junit
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_03ef1fbc/src/test/java/com/estudo/minhasfinancas/service/UsuarioServiceTest.java:[3,1] static import only from classes and interfaces
remote:        [ERROR]
```

Comment: You are missing the maven dependency....

Comment: You code is using import of JUnit 4 and not of JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5) because it would be `org.junit.jupiter.*` ...

Comment: I am using Junit 5 with import org.junit.jupiter and the maven dependency of Junit 5